# Fabric JS - Shapes are not displaying

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS and the shapes are not displaying, my code is on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/270t9hfs/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    function addRectangle(){
                    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
                        left: 100,
                        top: 100,
                        fill: "red",
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                        angle: 0
                    });
                    canvas.add(rect);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example has a working `addRectangle` function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        
        li a{
            display: block;
            color: #000;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        /* Change the link color on hover */
        li a:hover {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }
        
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        button { margin-top: 9px }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <button onclick="addRectangle()">Add Rectangle</button>
    <button onclick="addTriangle()">Add Triangle</button>
    <button onclick="addCircle()">Add Circle</button>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    function addRectangle(){
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fill: "red",
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            angle: 0
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Two issues were breaking your code:

1. Missing Fabric JS library
2. Initialising your Fabric JS canvas before the DOM had loaded. Moving the JavaScript to the bottom of the page resolves this. Alternatively you could use JavaScript to listen for when the DOM has loaded.